# Instability of equilibrium points of system $x'=y^3$, $y'=\cos(x)\sin(x)$

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, lyapunov-functions, hamilton-equations

We take a look at the system
$$
x'=y^3, \quad y'= \cos(x)\sin(x).
$$
It has a Hamiltonian $H(x, y) = \frac{1}{4}y^4 - \frac{\sin(x)^2}{2}$ for $(x, y) \in \mathbb{R}^2$.

It is clear that the points $n\pi$ ($n \in \mathbb{Z}$) are Lyapunov-stable equilibrium points (use Lyapunov function $H$). The equilibrium points $\frac{n \pi}{2}$ ($n \in \mathbb{Z}$) however are not so easy to handle. It is intuitively clear to me, that these are unstable, since $H$ suggests that the orbits close to these equilibra are approximately ellipses centered around the Lyapunov-stable equilibria. So I suggest that the familiy $\frac{n \pi}{2}$ consists of unstable equilibria.

Is there any mathematically rigorous way to show this, maybe using the definition of stability? Linearization and a direct Lyapunov method using $H$ don't help here as far as I'm concerned.

Comment: The Hamiltonian should be a difference, not a sum. The symplectic gradient is, e.g., given by $x'=H_y$, $y'=-H_x$, fitting the present system. This will shift the stability nature of the equilibrium points. For example $(0,0)$ is easily identified as saddle point.

Comment: You are right, thank you. But how exactly do you see that $(0, 0)$ is easily a saddle point=

Comment: Because structurally it looks like the vector field of $x'=y$, $y'=x$, which is well-known. For that it is really only important that the right sides are odd functions (in the opposite variables) and their growth behavior around the equilibrium point.

Comment: Okay... That is clear to me. But still, I would love to see a completely rigorous argument

Comment: You can try applying the Chetaev instability theorem.

Comment: Never heard of that one, thank you!